# How do you get the mount point/disk drive of a USB stick in cross-platform C++ or C?

Tags: c++, usb

I'm trying to get the mount point(linux/osx) or disk drive (windows) of a specific USB mass storage device.

I can use libusb to determine if the correct device is inserted but how do I determine where it is mounted?

I'm using C++ but I assume C code would work just as well. Cross-platform code would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard library provides no facilities for this, so true cross platform compatibility is not possible. On Windows you use a combination of GetLogicalDrives, and GetLogicalDriveType, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365730(v=VS.85).aspx). You could probably map that information to your device by using GetVolumeInformationByHandleW.